# Find Fraction using LP

Tags: python, linear-programming

I have two polygons `BP` and `GP` described by the set of inequalities constraints `-x+y<=1 and x+y<= 5 and x-y<=3 and -y <= 0` for the Black Polygon and `-1<=x<=4 and 0 <= y <= 3` for the Green Polygon.

[image]

My goal here is to use an LP to find the optimal solution of a fraction problem: given that `B` is in GP what is the maximum value `lambda` such that

> B = lambda*B_BP + (1-lambda)*B_GP

In other words I would like to find the largest fraction of `B`that is inside the polygon in the above sense. For that I am struggling to write a LP program, I think that if we write BP as a matrix inequality condition we get that every `B_BP` is such that  `M_BP*B_BP <= C` were `C` is a the vector `(1,5,3,0)` and `M_BP` is the matrix `((-1,1),(1,1),(1,-1),(0,-1))`. So I think it should go with something like, given B = x_1+x_2

> maximize lambda
>
> subject to M_BP*L_BP <= C_B
>
> and B_BP >= 0

Where I suppose (this is all my attempt, might be all very wrong) that `L_BP = (x,y)` vector and `lambda = (x+y)/normalization` and also that `C_B` relates somehow to the vector `B`.

Sorry if my first question is too messy, I'm starting here.

Comment: I would like to help you with your problem but I don't get the whole question.
B is a transformation from B_BP to B_GP but you never defined what are B_BP and B_GP.
Just try to write your quest well defined.

Comment: B_BP is any point inside BP and similarly for B_GP, also B is not a transformation but a random point in GP, sorry if my description was confusing and thank you a lot for considering my question

Comment: Okay, BP is a supset ob GP. If I choose lambda = 1 B is some point in BP and therefore in GP. Is that correct? So lambda must be some number greater or equal 1.

Comment: No, lambda must be less then or equal to 1, if lambda is 1 then B is just inside BP and if lambda is less then 0 I want to know what is the MAX lambda such that a portion of B a.k.a B_BP will be inside the black poly. So given B what is the largest possible convex decomposition of B such that one of the decomposed vectors lie inside BP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think it is possible to solve this exact, in a mathematical sense. Let me explain. Since the objective function is linear in lambda (as Superkogito points out), a maximum (or minimum) is always achieved in one of the corner points. By using this, you can calculate lambda.

Let me start with some simple examples. For any point within the black polygon it is clear that lambda is 1: you can just put B = B_BP. Now let's take B = (-1, 3). If you would take any black point other than B_BP = (-1, 0) and have lambda > 0, then with any green point within the square your x-coordinate will be higher than -1. So the best you can do is put B_BP = (-1, 0). Then the green point should be B_GP = (-1, 3), therefore lambda = 0.

Following the same logic, you can see that on the edge defined by the endpoints (-1, 0) and (-1, 3) you would always use B_BP = (-1, 0) and B_GP = (-1, 3). Going up this edge, lambda will decrease from 1 to 0. In (-1, 1) lambda = 2/3, in (-1, 2) lambda = 1/3. Same thing for the upper edge between (-1, 3) and (2, 3): in (0, 3) lambda = 1/3 and so forth. For the green triangle with corner (4, 3) you have to use (4, 3) as endpoint. Then in (3, 3) for example lambda = 1/2.

The interesting issue is obviously in the inner parts of the triangles. Here also B_GP is one of the corners, and B_BP is on the black line that is the side of the triangle. You can show this by assuming that there is another solution where this is not the case, and then proving that it is possible to increase lambda, by shifting B_GP or B_BP a little bit to the left or to the right. A complete mathematical proof would be too long for here, I guess. Now let's take the triangle on the left, with green corner (-1, 3) and the black side between (-1, 0) and (2, 3). Then for maximal lambda, B_GP = (-1, 3) and B_BP is on the black side. Because B = lambda * B_BP + (1 - lambda) * B_GP, this gives you two equations. And because B_BP is on the line y = x + 1, that gives you a third equation. From these you can solve the x- and y-coordinates of B_BP and lambda (given a point B).

I have done this and arrive at lambda = (Bx - By + 4) / 3. The coordinates of B_BP are then B_BPx = (Bx + 1 + lambda) / lambda and B_BPy = (By - 3 + 3 * lambda) / lambda (just fill in the lambda). For example, for the point (0, 2) you would have lambda = 2/3. You can do exactly the same for the other two triangles, I have done that as well.

I'll summarize:

For the left triangle: lambda = (Bx - By + 4) / 3

For the upper right triangle: lambda = (-By - Bx + 7) / 2

For the lower right triangle: lambda = By - Bx + 4

Programming this is now trivial. If you want, I can give you the corresponding coordinates of B_BP for the other two triangles, please let me know. By the way, you can arrive at them by drawing a straight line through the corner of the triangle and B.

Of course this only works when the objective function is linear. In other cases you would have to use an approach as suggested by Superkogito. I hope I have understood your question correctly, please forgive me if not! At least I found it a nice mathematical challenge.

Comment: That is a great answer, both were great and this is the idea, but my hope was going to be such that I would have a lp programing so that I would be able to generalize it for any polygon (or even higher dimensions) but this answer of yours really got the point.

Comment: And also, at least it made me visualize in a better way what I was thinking. Indeed very helpful!

Comment: Thank you R.W, good that it helped. With respect to generalization: you can generalize this approach to as many dimensions as you like and with any polygon, as long as the equation B = lambda*B_BP + (1-lambda)*B_GP stays as it is, i.e. linear. You will only need LP programming when there is something like lambda^2 in the equation. Good luck!

Comment: It is not clear to me the generalization for polytopes of any dimension but I appreciate the tips! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem needs a better formulation in my opinion. I am not sure if this solves your issue but hopefully it helps. So I suggest using [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) to solve this optimization problem and just by inverting the sign or using the inverse you can transform your maximization into a minimization.

Also, since you are basing your code on random points from BP, GP and the random point B, you should feed those also into your input vector. From the input vector you can compute the lambda coefficients (I named this variable k in my code). This approach will return the values of the input vector that fulfills the constraints with the smallest output of the objective function `fun` aka the largest `kx` and largest `ky`.

The previously explained approach can be implemented as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize


# compute k
def k(x):
    x_bp, y_bp = x[0], x[1]
    x_gp, y_gp = x[2], x[3]
    bx  , by   = x[4], x[5]

    # compute k
    kx = (bx - x_gp) / (x_bp - x_gp)
    ky = (by - y_gp) / (y_bp - y_gp)
    return kx, ky


# define objctive/cost function
def fun(x):
    kx, ky = k(x)
    return 1 / kx + 1 / ky

# define constraints (bp raandom point constraints)
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] - 5},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] - x[1] - 3})

# init bounds 
bnds = ((None, None), (0, None), 
        (-1., 4.), (0., 3.), 
        (-1., 4.), (0., 3.))

# init vars vec
#x = [x_bp, y_bp, x_gp, y_gp, bx,   by]
x0 = [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.5, 0.6, 0.5]

# optimize 
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, 
                              x0, 
                              bounds=bnds, 
                              constraints=cons)

# print result
print("optimal x: ", np.round(res.x, 3))

# print optimal k 
print("optimal k: ", np.round(k(res.x), 3))
```

Note that you might need to tweak the code a bit and play with the initial value `x0` and bounds but this should do the trick. The posted snippet results in the following output:

```
optimal x:  [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.5]
optimal k:  [-1.5 -0. ]
```

Comment: The problem is that in my optimization I have only as an input the points b, and the format of the polygons: I cannot insert the variables  x_bp, y_bp, x_gp, y_gp, because in some sense I would like to find them.

Comment: you can simply insert what is unknown (what you are looking for) and define what is known as `args` or `consts`.